# magento 2 get all products video gallery

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, video, product-video

I need to get all videos in one page, How I can get all the videos or get all product that has video?

Comment: can you please explain in brief.

Answer (score 0):

I do like this. hope this code helps to another

```
        $result=[];
    $collection=$this->productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect("*");

    $collection->addMediaGalleryData();

    /**
     * @var $product  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    foreach($collection as $product)
    {
        foreach($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $mediaAttribute)
        {
            if($mediaAttribute->getMediaType() == "external-video")
            {
              $result[]=$product;
            }
        }
    }
```